# Difference Between GLM predict Output in R vs. GLM predict Output in Python (statsmodels) Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic, python, generalized-linear-model

I am just working on trying to port some R script to Python. I am fairly new to the Python language. I have been going through the R script and converting it. But there is a part that is stumping me,
where I ran a logistic regression in statsmodels GLM, but when I use the predict method afterwards,
the results I am getting from statsmodels is not comparable to what I get running R.

I just need some help in figuring out how Python is running, to lead to the differences. To make it
easier for reproducibility, I will include both my R and Python scripts. I will post my R scripts
first, followed by the Python along with the data.

```
# R Script

# the dataframe
dfR = data.frame('DV' = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 'IV1' = c(3.58517, 2.07391, 0.55865, 1.08131, 0.15004, 2.9959, 1.29169, 1.50527, 0.81436, -1.90697),
                 'IV2' = c(3.73935, 0.53802, 1.73509, 3.01428, 2.7058, 1.97086, 3.98669, 2.67305, 3.18234, 1.39142),
                 'IV3' = c(0.8255, 4.8461, 4.3388, 2.565, 5.6754, 5.4174, 7.666, -0.1009, 0.4374, 3.6268)
)
print(dfR)


Y <- dfR[,1]
X <- dfR[,2:length(dfR[1,])]
XS <- scale(X)


XS.svd<-svd(XS)
Q<-XS.svd$v
P<-XS.svd$u
Z<-P%*%t(Q)
ZS <- scale(Z)

Lambda<-solve(t(ZS)%*%ZS)%*%t(ZS)%*%XS

logrfit <- glm(unlist(Y) ~ ZS, family=binomial)
summary(logrfit)

unstCoefs<-coef(logrfit)
unstCoefs
b<-unstCoefs[2:length(unstCoefs)]
b

# **where there is a difference between R and Python**
LpredY<-predict(logrfit, newdata=dfR,type="response")
print(LpredY)
```

Below is the Python code, it follows the R code exactly, with just minor variations to be consistent with
how Python outputs stuff

```
# Python Code

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from numpy import linalg
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# the dataframe
dfP = pd.DataFrame(
    {'DV': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     'IV1': [3.58517, 2.07391, 0.55865, 1.08131, 0.15004, 2.9959, 1.29169, 1.50527, 
             0.81436, -1.90697],
     'IV2': [3.73935, 0.53802, 1.73509, 3.01428, 2.7058, 1.97086, 3.98669, 2.67305, 
             3.18234, 1.39142],
     'IV3': [0.8255, 4.8461, 4.3388, 2.565, 5.6754, 5.4174, 7.666, -0.1009, 0.4374, 3.6268]
    }
    )
print(dfP)


Y = dfP.iloc[:, 0]
X = dfP.iloc[:, 1:]
XS = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)


P, _, Q = np.linalg.svd(XS, full_matrices=False)
Z = P @ Q
ZS = StandardScaler().fit_transform(Z)

Lambda = linalg.inv(ZS.T @ ZS) @ ZS.T @ XS

dfZS = pd.DataFrame(ZS, columns=X.columns)
dfXY = pd.concat([Y, dfZS], axis=1)

ZS_columns = list(dfXY.iloc[:, 1:].columns)
ZS2_columns = ' + '.join(str(i) for i in ZS_columns)

formula = 'Y ~ {}'.format(ZS2_columns)
mod = smf.glm(formula=formula, data=dfXY, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
print(mod.summary())

b = mod.params[1:] 

# **where there is a difference between R and Python**
LpredY = mod.predict(dfP)
print(LpredY)
```

The only part that is not consistent with the output from R is the `LpredY` variable. Just need some
assistance in figuring out the discrepancies.

Comment: Hi, statsmodels doesn't include intercept terms by default; try adding a column of ones to your data.

Comment: I used the formula approach in statsmodels, which I think, [defaults to inclusion of the intercept](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm_formula.html)

Comment: Oh TIL (as long as your output has a row that says "intercept" :)).

Answer (score 0):

After much reading, I came upon the solution. It turns out that the following script in `R GLM, family=binomial`

```
predict(logrfit, newdata=dfR, type="response")
```

has its counterpart in `Python statsmodel GLM, family=sm.families.Binomial()` as

```
model.mu
```

This means that in the question I posted earlier for this R script:

```
predict(logrfit, newdata=dfR, type="response")
```

The equivalent Python form is not `mod.predict(dfP)`, but rather,

```
mod.mu
```

where `mod` is the name I gave my GLM object

Below are some links to the information on that: [yhat = res.mu](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html#:%7E:text=We%20extract%20information,yhat%20%3D%20res.mu) and
[mu: ndarray](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html#:%7E:text=Default%20is%20Gaussian.-,mundarray,family%20for%20more%0Ainformation.,-n_trialsndarray)

Comment: `predict` used in-sample and `mu` should be the same numbers. Maybe dfR, dfP is not the appropriately transformed design matrix for prediction.